# Show a modal by clicking a custom link inside the tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, bootstrap-modal, tinymce-4

I am try to pop up a bootstrap modal clicking a custom link inside the tinymce editor.

custom link insert and event binding done like this.

```
var contentURL = '<a class="lesson-content" href ="'+contentId+'" data-contentId="'+contentId+'" data-type="'+contentType+'">View</a>
```

Inset my custom link to editor
`top.tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', true, contentURL);`

Bind event done like this
    `top.tinymce.activeEditor.dom.bind(top.tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('a[data-contentId="'+contentId+'"]'),'click',function(e){
                console.log("Test");alert('Test);
                $('#deletecontent_modal').modal('show');
            });`

When I click this link console.log message shows, but alert() and modal pop up don't work  and show error message like this,

> NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED:  /lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js Line 6

Any idea how to fix this ?